# Selenium webdriver- Identify an element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to automation (selenium).Scenario :To identify the element of the mobile title on any mobile site(eg:flipkart).I wanted to know whether there is any other way apart from the href/title to identify the element using selenium webdriver?I want to make it generic as the mobile phone might not be available after sometime.

http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/sony~brand/pr?sid=tyy,4io&_pop=flyout&otracker=hp_submenu_new_mobile_Mobiles_Sony#jumpTo=228|20

Use this url for the scenario.

I am using Java as the language.Selenium version : 1.10.0
As per my knowledge we can use id,name,css and xpath to identify the element,but what do i do when i have to **always** select the second phone title no matter which phone it is.How do I create the xpath for this?or is there any other way to do so?Please let me know.

These are the html tags for the first and second phones for the above url:

```html
<a class="fk-display-block" title="Sony Xperia SP (Black)" href="/sony-xperia-sp/p/itmdjmz3z9hgbhdm?pid=MOBDJMZ2U6JFHZZH&ref=ab7f3941-7bfb-4119-a446-555c42f4248a"> Sony Xperia SP (Black) </a>

<a class="fk-display-block" title="Sony Xperia Miro (Black)" href="/sony-xperia-miro/p/itmdda7crgzwqzhp?pid=MOBDDA5Y6BKX6VHR&ref=f8fea7a0-d9c0-4264-8fc9-959f09407436"> Sony Xperia Miro (Black) </a>
```

As we can observe that the only difference between two phones are the title , the href and the link text.The class is the same for all of the phones.

Comment: What language? There are several ways of identifying elements, there isn't actually one answer to this.

Comment: Needs more information, including the above - what type of language, what version of Selenium, what code are you using right now and what do you intend to do?

Comment: You updated your original question with more information, great, but you left out what code you are using right now. That is, what selectors are you using right now? Show us them.

Comment: I am just a beginner learning how to use selenium so.there is no code that I am creating as of now.

Answer (score 2):

You can do by one of the following ways:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sony Xperia Miro (Black)"));
```

OR,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Sony Xperia Miro (Black)']"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java, you should be able to use [`By.linkText`](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-link-text) or [`By.partialLinkText`](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-partial-link-text):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sony Xperia Miro (Black)"));
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Sony"));
```

For `By.partialLinkText` you may want to use the `findElements()` method if you expect many elements to match the partial link text:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText("Sony"));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Fire Bug**

Firebug is a Firefox add-on that we will use to inspect the HTML elements of the web application under test.

- Use Firefox to navigate to Firebug’s download page
  `https://getfirebug.com/downloads/`
- Click on the download link.
- Click the “Add to Firefox” button.
- Click “Install Now.”

  **Launch Firebug**
  Press F12 or Click on the Firebug button on the upper right corner of the Firefox window.

**FirePath**

FirePath is a Firebug extension that adds a development tool to edit, inspect and generate XPath expressions, CSS selectors and JQuery selectors.

- Use Firefox to navigate to FirePath’s download page

  `https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/`
- Click the “Add to Firefox” button.
- Click “Install Now.”

  **Launch FirePath**
  Press F12 or Click on the Firebug button on the upper right corner of the Firefox window, FirePath starts along with FireBug

**WebDriver Element Locator**

WebDriver Element Locator is also a Firefox add-on. This add-on is designed to support and speed up the creation of WebDriver scripts by easing the location of web elements.

- Use Firefox to navigate to WebDriver Element Locator’s download page

  `https ://addons .mozilla .org/en-US /firefox/ addon/ element- locator- for-webdriv/`

  ***`remove the spaces between the link`***
- Click the “Add to Firefox” button.
- Click “Install Now.”

Answer (score 1):

Check the docs for your language

You can find elements or lists of elements based on xpath, css_selector, class_name, id, name, tag_name, link_text or partial_link_text